# Attaching event listener to an svg element in react

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg

I am pretty new to React.
I have d3 map in my react web application.I need to attach a click event to the map.Could anyone please let me know how can I attach a click to this map?

---

```
const County = ({geoPath,feature}) => (
    //<path d={geoPath(feature)} style={{fill: color}} title={feature.id} />

    <path d={geoPath(feature)} style={{fill: color(Math.random()*5)}} title={feature.id} />
);

----------  
render(){
      if(!this.props.usTopoJson){
          return null;
      }else{
          let color = 'rgb(42,73,120)';
          //let color = 'orange';
          const us = this.props.usTopoJson,
                statesMesh=topojson.mesh(us,us.objects.countries.geometries,(a,b) => a !==b),
                countries = topojson.feature(us,us.objects.countries).features;
            return(
                //<g>
               <g ref={(g) => { this.myG = g; }}>
                {countries.map((feature) => 
                        <County geoPath={this.geoPath} 
                                feature={feature}
                                key={feature.id}
                                quantize={this.quantize} />)}
                 <path d={this.geoPath(statesMesh)} style={{fill:'color',stroke:'#aaa',
                                                            strokeLinejoin:'round'}}/>

                </g>
            );
      }

  }
```

Comment: Did you try adding `onClick` as an attribute of `<County/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<County geoPath={this.geoPath} 
           onClick={someHandleClickFunc}
           feature={feature}
           key={feature.id}
           quantize={this.quantize} />
```